# How do I scale a rectangle to another rectangle (such as a picture to a window) preserving aspect ratio with the option to fill?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, geometry, scaling

I'm putting this here because the algorithm for doing this is more difficult to find than it should be. Hopefully Google will cache this.

The problem is: you have a bitmap and a window. You want to draw the bitmap inside a window, filling the window, keeping the aspect ratio, as the window resizes.

You may also want to be able to fit it the other way, so that you can draw the image "over" the window, and all the area in the window will be filled. This will clip out some of the image. I present in the answer a simple algorithm for doing so.

Comment: MSDN [has a good discussion of this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530115(v=vs.85).aspx) as well as some useful sample code.

Comment: Ah yes! The "Scale" flag sets it to "pan and scan" mode, as the article calls it, as opposed to "letterbox" mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation that uses integer math only.

The algorithm first stretches both dimensions, preserving aspect ratio. The new size is calculated, assuming that the respective other dimension occupies the entire space. Of these new dimensions, the one that overshoots the available area is set to the maximum possible value, while the other is scaled back, preserving aspect ratio. (For *pan and scan* (*bScale* is set to `true`) mode, the dimension that doesn't overshoot the available space is set to occupy the entire range.)

(Note: If *sizePicture* is an empty rectangle, this function returns a rectangle that stretches one pixel to the left and one pixel up, either from the origin, or the center.)

```
RECT size_rect( RECT& rcScreen,
                RECT& sizePicture,
                bool bCenter/*,
                bool bScale*/ ) {

    int clientWidth = rcScreen.right - rcScreen.left;
    int clientHeight = rcScreen.bottom - rcScreen.top;
    int picWidth = sizePicture.right - sizePicture.left;
    int picHeight = sizePicture.bottom - sizePicture.top;
    // Calculate new content size
    int contentWidth = ::MulDiv( clientHeight, picWidth, picHeight );
    int contentHeight = ::MulDiv( clientWidth, picHeight, picWidth );

    // Adjust dimensions to fit inside client area
    if ( contentWidth > clientWidth ) {
    // To use the bScale parameter that allows the image to fill the entire
    // client area, use the following if-clause instead.
    //if (    ( bScale && ( contentWidth < clientWidth ) )
    //     || ( !bScale && ( contentWidth > clientWidth ) ) ) {
        contentWidth = clientWidth;
        contentHeight = ::MulDiv( contentWidth, picHeight, picWidth );
    } else {
        contentHeight = clientHeight;
        contentWidth = ::MulDiv( contentHeight, picWidth, picHeight );
    }

    RECT rect = { 0 };
    ::SetRect( &rect, 0, 0, contentWidth, contentHeight );
    if ( bCenter ) {
        // Calculate offsets to center content
        int offsetX = ( clientWidth - contentWidth ) / 2;
        int offsetY = ( clientHeight - contentHeight ) / 2;
        ::OffsetRect( &rect, offsetX, offsetY );
    }
    return rect;
}
```

Comment: "Scale" determines the way it fits the window. Should it preserve the aspect ratio and show the whole picture, leaving parts of the window empty? Or should it scale it up so that it fills the window, clipping off parts of the image? That's what it does. Sorry for poor explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Make two RECT. One is the window you wish to fit to (passed into rcScreen), and the other holds the dimensions of the picture:

```
(pseudo-code)
RECT window;
GetClientRect(hwnd,&window)
RECT bitmap_rect;
BITMAP bitmap;
bitmap_rect.left = bitmap_rect.top = 0;
bitmap_rect.right = bitmap.bmWidth;
bitmap_rect.bottom = bitmap.bmHeight;
RECT draw_rect = size_rect(window,bitmap_rect,true,true);
```

Then StretchBlt it:

```
StretchBlt(toDC, draw_rect.left, draw_rect.top, draw_rect.right, draw_rect.bottom, fromDC, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
```

This is the function: (note there is no case for bCenter = false and Scale = true). **bCenter is flag for "center picture in window." Scale is flag for "pan and scan mode" instead of "letterbox," useful if you are using an image as a window background that you want resized but don't want to have letterboxes. **

```
RECT size_rect(RECT& rcScreen,
    RECT& sizePicture,
    bool bCenter,
    bool Scale)
{
    RECT rect = rcScreen;
    double dWidth = rcScreen.right - rcScreen.left;
    double dHeight = rcScreen.bottom - rcScreen.top;
    double dAspectRatio = dWidth / dHeight;

    double dPictureWidth = sizePicture.right - sizePicture.left;
    double dPictureHeight = sizePicture.bottom - sizePicture.top;
    double dPictureAspectRatio = dPictureWidth / dPictureHeight;

    double nNewHeight = dHeight;
    double nNewWidth = dWidth;
    double nHeightCenteringFactor = 0;
    double nWidthCenteringFactor = 0;

    double xstart = rcScreen.left;
    double ystart = rcScreen.top;

    if (dPictureAspectRatio > dAspectRatio)
    {
        if (bCenter && Scale) {
            nNewWidth = dPictureWidth*(1 / (dPictureHeight / dHeight));
            xstart = rcScreen.left - ((nNewWidth / 2) - (dWidth / 2));
        }
        else {
            nNewHeight = (int)(dWidth / dPictureWidth*dPictureHeight);
            if (bCenter)
                ystart = ((dHeight - nNewHeight) / 2) + rcScreen.top;
        }

    }
    else if (dPictureAspectRatio < dAspectRatio)
    {
        if (bCenter && Scale) {
            nNewHeight = dPictureHeight*(1 / (dPictureWidth / dWidth));
            ystart = rcScreen.top - ((nNewHeight / 2) - (dHeight / 2));
        }
        else{
            nNewWidth = (dHeight / dPictureHeight*dPictureWidth);

            if (bCenter)
                xstart = ((dWidth - nNewWidth) / 2) + rcScreen.left;
        }
    }
    SetRect(&rect, xstart, ystart, nNewWidth, nNewHeight);
    return rect;
}
```